# Working with text decoration color

Tags: html, css

I want to change text decoration underline color on hover. But I want underline color to be different than text color.

I have managed to do this on firefox using "`-moz-text-decoration-color`". But this does not support other major browser.

```
p{
text-decoration: underline;
text-decoration-color: red;
-moz-text-decoration-color: red; /* Code for Firefox */
}
```

Any idea to make it working on other browsers.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using text decoration use border:bottom 1px solid red; Then change the colour on hover.

Then change the line-height accordingly on the p tag to the desired space underneath.

This way you can guarantee it will work in all browsers.

```
.box a {text-decoration:none;border-bottom: 1px solid red;width:auto; }
.box a:hover {border-bottom: 1px solid blue;}
```

Working Demo Here http://jsfiddle.net/Lme3w/

Comment: Hi my <a href is inside a box div. <div class="box"><a href="<venda_dispview icat=table_decor>">Table Decor</a></div> The size of the box is bigger than the text. So underline becomes bigger than the text –

Comment: Put the border-bottom on the <a> tag and set the width to auto. also set text-decoration: none;

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: I have added an example above in my original post.

Comment: I have tried .box a:hover{border-bottom: 1px solid #F47920; text-decoration: none; width:auto;} But still underline appears on full box widh not the text width?

Comment: Try float:left on the <a>.

Can you send me a link? it would be more effective.

Comment: Your putting width auto on the a:hover, put width:auto just on the a. As i have done above. Please send link :)

Comment: Still didnt help. underline becomes full width?

Answer (score 0):

This style is [**only supported in Firefox**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-color)

You may want to apply a transparent (or specific color) bottom border to the element, then apply a color to it on hover instead.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5GZN/)

```
a{
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent; /* <-- change transparent to a specific default color if desired */
  text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover{
  border-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Hi my a is inside a box div. <div class="box"><a href="<venda_dispview icat=table_decor>">Table Decor</a></div>  The size of the box is bigger than the text. So underline becomes bigger than the text

Comment: I have tried .box a:hover{border-bottom: 1px solid #F47920; text-decoration: none; width:auto;} But still underline appears on full box widh not the text width?

Answer (score 0):

```
p:hover{
text-decoration: underline;
text-decoration-color: red;
-moz-text-decoration-color: red; /* Code for Firefox */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use text-decoration instead of borders I'd just wrap the text in a `<span>` and colour that.

Example:

```
<p><span>Text here</span></p>

p {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
p:hover {
    color: red;
}
p span {
    color: #000;
}
```